# Modal opens and closes immediately

Tags: javascript, modal-dialog

I am attempting to display a modal with results of a php query, after a button is submitted, but the modal flashes onto the screen, instead of remaining until it is manually closed, due to the fact that submitting a form refreshes the page.

```
<script>
var modal = document.getElementById("myModal");
var btn = document.getElementById("submitForm");
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];
var form = document.getElementsByClassName("myForm")[0];

btn.addEventListener('click', openModal);
function openModal() {
    form.submit();
    modal.style.display = "block";
    console.log("shiet");
}

span.addEventListener('click', closeModal);
function closeModal(){
    modal.style.display = "none";
}

window.addEventListener('click', function(event){
  if (event.target == modal) {
    modal.style.display = "none";
  }
});
</script>
```

On clicking the button id=submitForm, I want a modal to pop up, containing the results of a php script. This modal can then be closed by clicking off the screen or by activating closeModal, by clicking a span element.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
window.addEventListener('click', function(event){
  if (event.target != modal) {
    modal.style.display = "none";
  } else {
    modal.style.display = "block";
  }
});
```

Here I meant that if the user is clicking on the window but not on the modal, then hide that; else keep the modal visible...

I think the modal flashes because of this reason!

I hope this works!

Comment: It is not this. I've tried setting the display value as "block" as default, and it works. The problem is that openModal submits my form, which refreshes the page and causes my modal (which opens up) to disappear.

Comment: Then I think you got the answer! : )

Comment: I know what causes the issue, I don't know how to solve it.